# Conditional formatting based on value with offset

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am looking for some help with the code for my issue. Cant quite figure out where to start.
What i want to do, is to get a certain range(by use of offset), to be colored if a value in a cell, is equal to a name in a list.

I would like to do it by conditional formatting i Vba because i need to do it many times (it is a big sheet)

Example:
In cell B5 the value is "Juliet".
I have a list of names i column K and in column L i have colors.
I want to conditional format range B3 to B6, if "juliet" Appears on the list, and in the color given next to "juliet".

I need to repeat itself, så the placement of "Juliet" could be anywhere, but always color the name, 2 cells above and 1 cell below.

Hope someone can help me get started the right way.

[image: Example]

**Edited**

```
Sub Findname_and_Color()
Dim rng As Range

Dim cell As Range
Dim objColorStop As ColorStop
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set rng = Worksheets("Kalender").Range("F5:KI232") ' Adjust Range as needed
Set ws = Worksheets("xx")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rngNam As Range: Set rngNam = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
        Dim f As Range, prevVal As String
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set f = rngNam.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                rng.Range(cell.Offset(-2, -5), cell.Offset(0, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = f.Offset(, 3).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If

End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: A conditional formatting rule can't use the color from a specific cell on the sheet. You either need to "hard-code" that color in the rule, or use VBA.

Comment: Please, try the solution I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional Formatting is not suitable for changing other cells than the changed one. Please, copy the next code event in the sheet in discussion code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'it works only for A SINGLE CELL CHANGE
   
   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:H")) Is Nothing And Target.Row >= 3 Then
        Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Me.Range("K" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rngNam As Range: Set rngNam = Range("K2:K" & lastR)
        Dim f As Range, prevVal As String
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Set f = rngNam.Find(what:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Me.Range(Target.Offset(-2), Target.Offset(1)).Interior.ColorIndex = f.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        Else
          Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            prevVal = Target.Value
            Target.Value = ""
            Set f = rngNam.Find(what:=prevVal, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Me.Range(Target.Offset(-2), Target.Offset(1)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
          Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

It will also clear the cell interior when the name is cleared.

To see the sheet code module window, please right click on the sheet you try entering the respective names, choose `View Code` and paste the above code in the opening window.

Of course, you must have the mentioned Names (in "K:K" column) and the corresponding interior cells color in the next one ("L:L").

**Edited**:

If you need to use the reference names range from a different sheet, you should only replace:

```
   Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Me.Range("K" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim rngNam As Range: Set rngNam = Range("K2:K" & lastR)
```

with:

```
   Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'use here the sheet name you need
   Dim lastR As Long: lastR = sh.Range("K" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim rngNam As Range: Set rngNam = sh.Range("K2:K" & lastR)
```

Everything remains as it is. You do not need to run any code, you should only update the names range/corresponding colors in the sheet you need...

Comment: Hi Fane Duru, this is what i was looking for!
I do have two questions - can i change the "me.range" if the list with names in another sheet?

Comment: Of course, you can. Just fully qualifym the range. Now I am driving...

Comment: Is it possible, that it dosent depend on change, and then I put i an button to go trough every cell in the sheet, and then update them at once?
So that it isent a private sub, but a sub depending on a button?

Comment: Not, relly... I will show you how to do it after I will be at home.

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen I edited the above answer and (after **Edited**:) I explained what is to be replaced with what, to use a different sheet to keep the names/colors ranges. Please, test the suggested solution and send some feedback.

Comment: It also works like a charme!
Then my only question is, if it possible to run the macro on a button instead off change in a cell. (When i drag a cell, it dosent change, and i would like it to.

So i think, if it is possible, that i would like to run trough all cells in a range, and the color it (still with looking up a name in a list).

Can that be done?

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen Not sure if I am able to get you... Everything is possible if you know exactly what you want and clearly explain what is to be done, but in details. You said something about Conditional Formatted, which does not allow dragging, specifically in the required circumstances when different rules/formulas should be set for the adiacent cells. When you say **all cells in a range**, what do you have in mind? What range?

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen Doing as you say, it would be not so complicated to color the respective cells interior, but **based on what logic to clear the color in ranges where no such a name exist, anymore, because they have been deleted/cleared/dragged**?

Comment: I will try to explain better.. :)
I would be prefferable if it would look trough cells when i manually start the macro(like the answer AlessioFranzini).
I would like to combine the part from your script where you look for a value in a list, but does it on the code "For each Cell in range".

I have a calender, where i type in familytime, and then drag them trough cerveral days. I would like not to have to manually change a cell, when it is repeated 365 days for a year. 

I will put in a piece of code in the original post, where i tried to combine them, but it dosent sucseed....

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen So, you do not need the code to clear the color if the respective name string are deleted/cleared. Would such an understanding be  correct one? If so, and have only the names you show, it is good to accept the code you mention, since he better understood your need and was the first. I work in Excel from many years but I never felt the need to drag cells content. Neither now I am not able to understand why this need. If more such names, please specify the req. range (**"What range"**)? If you specify it, I can supply a piece of code to do what (I understood) you need.

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen Now, you maybe can clarify some aspects of the way you work, respectively. I do not like working for something which I cannot understand why you did it that way: 1. If there is a specific name in a specific cell (with adjacent cells Above and Bellow) are colored, dragging the respective cell in another place, will not let the adiacent cells colored? If you drag all the respective cells, they will come with the appropriate color. Is it something wrong with my logic? If yes, please explain what.

Comment: @Pernille Sunds Eskildsen If not, you can make your first calendar using the event and disabling events, dragging whatever you want (the whole colored cells around the name one. And about the range to be processed, if you still prefer that way, do not tell that any range. If you color cells above and bellow, I do not want the code to be inefficient searching for the empty colored ones, too. Maybe editing the question and adding a picture of the sheet you work on, would make the project more understandable for me...

Comment: I actually see what you mean now, and understand why you prefer the change value. Because when you drag the Color still go with it. Think i Will use the change value piece! Because i still need it to take the color off when there is no text.
Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I came up with:

```
Sub find_name_and_fill_cells()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J21")   ' Adjust Range as needed
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value2 = "Maiken" Then
      Range(cell.Offset(-2, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' Adjust color as needed
    ElseIf cell.Value2 = "Hannah" Then
      Range(cell.Offset(-2, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 ' Adjust color as needed
    ElseIf cell.Value2 = "Juliet" Then
      Range(cell.Offset(-2, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 ' Adjust color as needed
    ElseIf cell.Value2 = "Beatrice" Then
      Range(cell.Offset(-2, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0)).Interior.ColorIndex = 55 ' Adjust color as needed
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

To change the range use your actual range and for the color please refer to [this link](https://www.automateexcel.com/excel-formatting/color-reference-for-color-index/).

To start the macro, open VBA Editor and insert a module. Then copy this macro inside, insert a button in a page, and then assign this macro to it. Then, each time you press the button the macro will run.

Comment: The action of coloring and clear coloring should be dynamic, triggered by the change itself. Do you intend to manually run the code? What about some thousands of rows? And, let us say, 50 such names... Then, the cell interior color should be cleared if the respective name is cleared...

Comment: In the example there are only 4 names, so i used 4 names in my code. I know that there are many better ways to do it but my code fulfills the requests of the user, the only thing he needs to change is the range because he didnt specify it in the post.

Comment: As you say, it is an "example". Usually people show an example of a range which could be bigger. If you think that clearing the names the color is good to remain so, on an empty range, it is your choice, but I do not think it should be so. He was speaking about Conditional Formatting, which acts exactly as I am saying. Except the fact that you cannot use Conditional Formatting to change something else than the changed one, you should create different formulas for the adiacent cells, which is complicated and I would say useless, since using the `Change` event is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a no-code solution and you don't have many combinations of names and colours, you could use a rule per colour like this:

[image]

With the formula:

```
=OR(A1=$J$2;A2=$J$2;A3=$J$2;IFERROR(OFFSET(A1;-1;0)=$J$2;))
```

It checks if A1 (as the first cell in my range with conditional formatting rule. Change it to your first cell), A2 (as the one below it), A3 (one more below it) and Offset -1 (to check the one above it when applicable) are equal to the cell of the name